# Как правильно построить запрос

Tags: c#, excel

Доброе утро всем, мне надо сделать выборку из Excel'a но мне надо не всё подряд, и только 1 и 4 столбец(1 столбец это с A6 до A11,  а второй с C4 до C8), как построить запрос, я пробовал так:

```
OleDbCommand MyCommand = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$A6:A11,C4:C8]", MyConnection);
```

Но он не работает :( Как правильно построить?

Answer (score 1):

```
MyCommand = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"select [Операция], [Код модели/артикул] from [rem$]", MyConnection);
```

Это как взять 2-ва столбца целиком.